Why is the index not used in the query execution plan?
To briefly summarize the problem I have, it is that the index does not work properly in queries, which is just a difference in the database.
I am currently using two databases. For convenience, we will call them database1 and database2.
There are also tables such as member table (TB_MBR_INFO) and chat table (TB_CHAR_ROOM).
The TB_CHAT_ROOM table contains seller and buyer member IDs.
I want to get the membership number of this member ID.
So the query I created is as follows.
SELECT 
    A.regdate AS REG_DT,
    (select MBR_NO from database2.TB_MBR_INFO USE INDEX (TB_MBR_INFO_MBR_ID_IDX) where MBR_ID = A.seller) AS SELL_MBR_NO,
    (select MBR_NO from database2.TB_MBR_INFO USE INDEX (TB_MBR_INFO_MBR_ID_IDX) where MBR_ID = A.buyer) AS PRCH_MBR_NO
FROM database1.TB_CHAT_ROOM A

However, if you look at the execution plan of the query, possible_keys does not exist, so the member table is being fully scanned.
id|select_type       |table      |type |possible_keys|key                   |key_len|ref|rows  |Extra                   |
--+------------------+-----------+-----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---+------+------------------------+
 1|PRIMARY           |A          |ALL  |             |                      |       |   |474031|                        |
 4|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|TB_MBR_INFO|index|             |TB_MBR_INFO_MBR_ID_IDX|62     |   |422098|Using where; Using index|
 3|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|TB_MBR_INFO|index|             |TB_MBR_INFO_MBR_ID_IDX|62     |   |422098|Using where; Using index|

For testing, I copied the chat table and moved it to database2, and the index was applied normally.
SELECT 
    A.regdate AS REG_DT,
    (select MBR_NO from database2.TB_MBR_INFO USE INDEX (TB_MBR_INFO_MBR_ID_IDX) where MBR_ID = A.seller) AS SELL_MBR_NO,
    (select MBR_NO from database2.TB_MBR_INFO USE INDEX (TB_MBR_INFO_MBR_ID_IDX) where MBR_ID = A.buyer) AS PRCH_MBR_NO
FROM database2.TB_CHAT_ROOM A

id|select_type       |table      |type|possible_keys         |key                   |key_len|ref            |rows |Extra                   |
--+------------------+-----------+----+----------------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+-----+------------------------+
 1|PRIMARY           |A          |ALL |                      |                      |       |               |62721|                        |
 4|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|TB_MBR_INFO|ref |TB_MBR_INFO_MBR_ID_IDX|TB_MBR_INFO_MBR_ID_IDX|62     |database2.A.buyer |1    |Using where; Using index|
 3|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|TB_MBR_INFO|ref |TB_MBR_INFO_MBR_ID_IDX|TB_MBR_INFO_MBR_ID_IDX|62     |database2.A.seller|1    |Using where; Using index|

The only difference between the two is the database. Columns and indexes are all the same.
I moved everything to database 1 and tested it, just in case, but the problem of the index not working still persists.
I really want to solve the problem. If you know the cause, don’t pass it by.

Is it a typo that in the first query you mix database1 and database2?

@TomekK No, that's exactly what I was trying to say to avoid confusion. In the first query, the current session is Database1. If database1 is omitted in database 1.TB_CHAT_ROOM, TB_CHAT_ROOM of database1 is used.

Looks like a bug that should be reported. Which MariaDB versions have you tested this with? Does it resolve if you don't force index? What about doing two left joins rather than a subquery? Looks odd that MBR_NO isn't the PK, however that's an application change.

What is the exact version of your mysql or mariadb? Did you confirm the problem exists in the other product?

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for each table in each db involved.  It sounds like a clash over dataype or collation.

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for each table in each db involved.
I'll go out on a limb and say that there is an inconsistency in the dataypes or collations.
The SHOWs will help spot it.

Thank you for the hint, the problem was due to a mismatch in the types of data columns. thank you
